# Software for the Analysis of Interaction Sequences?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a computer program for analysing sequential observational data for Ubuntu. Analog for GSEQ (Generalized Sequential Querier) which include SDIS (Sequential Data Interchange Standard).

What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GSEQ](http://www2.gsu.edu/~psyrab/gseq/) is software for Windows and is free of cost to [download](http://www.gsu.edu/~psyrab/GSEQ5Setup.exe).

It will not run natively on Ubuntu but it should work in [wine](http://www.winehq.org/)

The site states:

> It runs under Windows (95/98/Me/2000/XP/Vista) and on other operating systems that run Windows simulation software

Which I assume to be referring to wine.

EDIT:

I can confirm it runs OK in wine, although I have not tested it thoroughly as I have no idea what it is used for or how to use it.

[image: gseq in wine]

To acheive this you need to first [install wine](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wine) then download the [.exe file](http://www.gsu.edu/~psyrab/GSEQ5Setup.exe) and right click on it and click 'Open With Wine Windows Program Loader' then run the installer setup.

Comment: Thanks dv3500ea for your answer. I know this. Sometime I have problems with software under wine. I search over the Internet, but I can't found analog application for GSEQ - native Gnu/Linux. I will mark this question as answered. Maybe someday we will have native software as this one for our system.